# Writing Polytonic Greek with autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Forgive me if this is not the appropriate stackexchange community for this question.

I am trying to write an autohotkey script to write polytonic Greek. I couldn't find a method of writing polytonic Greek that I liked so I am writing my own. Here is my code so far:

```
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

:*?:α-)-::ἀ
```

I will admit that I do not understand the purpose of the first three lines of code. I simply copied it from another script (which works well).

Anyway, whenever I type α-)-, it remains α-)-, so evidently the script isn't working. However, when I changed the code to

`:*?:a-)-::ἀ`

then typing a-)- gives the result á¼€. I simply cannot explain this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're not saving the script file with sufficient encoding. You'll need to save the script with file with UTF-8-BOM encoding. If you're using Notepad++, you can find encodings from the `Encoding` option at the top. If you use normal Notepad, choose "save as" and the encoding dropdown menu will be next to the save button.

Comment: Yes, that did it, thank you!